# Web app for designing a schedule for mutiple concurrent tasks and many people

Tags: webapp-rec

We are doing a huge three-day event with many tasks that go on in parallel, done by many people (some team, some volunteers). We are looking for a web app that may help in the following tasks:

1. Create a detailed agenda for tasks and people
2. Enable volunteers to select what they want to do
3. Print the agenda in calendar view with details about who/where/when

It would be an added benefit if the web interface was easy to use; maybe there'd be a way to import .XLS or .CSV files with tasks/schedules.

Any recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with Doodle: http://doodle.com/

Create an event for your 3 dates, then restrict the selections for to limit the participant to one per event.
[image: Doodle Settings]

You can look at a test [here](http://www.doodle.com/uz9c2mavegbvfxza) or [here](http://www.doodle.com/uz9c2mavegbvfxzac4cbtqh3/admin) for the admin interface
(I couldn't find how to add more description for each timeslot though)

Comment: this is not exactly what I was looking for, but nevertheless a good way of doing it! :)

Answer (score 0):

you should give http://www.zoho.com/projects/ a try

and take a look at this list http://tomuse.com/top-10-best-free-online-project-management-application-services/

Answer (score 0):

I have never used it an a large scale project but have always been partial to [Remember the Milk](http://www.rememberthemilk.com/).